# Can I purchase v-bucks on my phone then have them transfer to my switch once they are bought?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Can I purchase v-bucks on my mobile phone then have it transfer to my switch too so while using the same linked account on both.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the same account on your phone as on your Switch, it would transfer as it's both on your account. Gameplay and any user data should be the same; the only thing that differs is the platform you play on.

Comment: Thanks so much! That really helps, so I can use itunes to purchase v-bucks on mobile then go onto my switch and the v-bucks will be there? Sorry I just really want to be sure so I do not waste money on mobile because I already have and i-tunes giftcard.

Comment: @Tanner: **if your two consoles are using the same Fortnite account**. What you're asking is sort of the same as if you were doing online banking on two different computers. As long as it's the same bank (Fortnite) and bank account (Fortnite user account), both computers will be showing you the same money.

Answer (score 0):

## You have to have both accounts linked.

First, if you haven't already linked your Nintendo account with an epic games account, you need to do that first, to sync your progress from mobile, or the other way around.
Then, once you purchase the V-Bucks, they should transfer from one place to the other.